# Routing to different controllers having same name at different locations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rails-routing

I am using Rocket_Pants gem to provide API access for my existing Rails app. I have two of controllers with the same name but stored in different locations:

I store the controller that handles HTTP requests in `app/controllers`, and the controller that handles API calls in sub-directory `API` of `app/controllers`.

I have the following in my Routes:

```
  # HTTP routing 
  resources :posts do
    collection do
      get 'search'
    end
  end

  # API routing
  api :version => 1 do
    resources :posts, :only => [:index, :show]
    resources :posts do
      collection do
        get 'search'
      end
    end
  end
```

However, when I `rake routes`, I got:

```
GET    /:version/posts/search(.:format)       posts#search {:version=>/(1)/, :format=>"json"}
GET    /:version/posts(.:format)              posts#index {:version=>/(1)/, :format=>"json"}
GET    /:version/posts/:id(.:format)          posts#show {:version=>/(1)/, :format=>"json"}
```

This means that my API routes are actually pointing to http controller and not API controller. How can I point my API routes to `API/posts#search` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this is your 2nd question tonight on the basics of Rails routing, I *strongly* recommend reading the **[Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)** on the topic.

For this issue, you're looking for a `scope`. This is explained in **[the guide above](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)**.

```
api version: 1 do
  scope module: "api" do
    resources :posts, only: [:index, :show] do
      collection do
        get 'search'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also

1. Your directory should be named `app/controllers/api`, not `app/controllers/API`
2. Your controller should be at `app/controllers/api/posts_controller.rb` with class name like `class Api::PostsController < ApplicationController`

I should also mention, I don't know or use `rocket_pants`, but their README suggests namespacing controllers for different versions in modules as well (another level of scoping above).

Comment: thanks a lot. I'll dig in scope in routing as you recommended.

Answer (score -1):

Better "pants rockety" answer.

routes.rb

```
api :version => 1, module: "api" do
  resources :foobars
```

folder structure

```
-controllers
  -api
    foobars_controller.rb
    etc
```

api_controller.rb

```
class ApiController < RocketPants::Base
```

foobars_controller.rb

```
class Api::EventsController < ApiController
  version 1
  etc
```